# How to Name Painted Graphics?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I was wondering if you could give a name to something that was painted.

Example:

```
`public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(int,int,int,int);
}`
```

Is it possible to give that rectangle a name so I can reference it in later code.

Comment: We're going to need to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried already in order to be of assistance.

Comment: Create an object that has a Name property and a Graphics property.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure for what exactly your are asking, but here's how you can save a 2 dimensional grid of variables:

```
String[][] rectangles = new String[100][100];
```

This above creates a field of Strings, 100*100 Strings big.
If you want to set the value for the field at x and y you do:

```
String[x][y] = "Hello World";
```

I did this with a String field, but you can use your own classes or something like int[][] as well. Depending on if you choose String[][], int[][] or yourClassName[][] you can store Strings, ints or yourClassNames in the field.

Comment: I was talking about naming actual graphical objects, which you can see now that I've edited the question. Not a String.

Comment: I would use a rect.class.
It has 4 points (a,b,c,d) and the get() and set() methods for it. Then you create a new rect(point,point,point,point) and use g.draw(rect.getPoint1(),...). You save all the rect objects in an array or sth.